# Triple Integrals Find the mass of the solid S made out of material with density f.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, maple

Find the mass of the solid S made out of material with density f in maple.
S is a ball bounded by the sphere (x−2)^2+(y+3)^2+(z−4)^2 =5; f(x, y, z)=x^2y^2.

How can I solve without changing it into a cylindrical coordinate? I tried the following but I am not sure if I did it right.
z limit from 4-sqrt(5-(x-2)^2 -(y+3)^2) to 4+sqrt(5-(x-2)^2 -(y+3)^2)
y limit from 3-sqrt(5-(x-2)^2) to 3+sqrt(5-(x-2)^2)
and x limit from -3 to 7.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In your limits of integration (for y) shouldn't you have `(y+3)^2` instead of your `(y-3)^2` term? And with radius sqrt(5) wouldn't your limits of integration (for x) be `2-sqrt(5)` to `2+sqrt(5)` instead of your `2-5=-3` to `2+5=7`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this for mistakes on my part...

```
restart;

VectorCalculus:-int(x^2*y^2,
                    [x,y,z] = Sphere(<2,-3,4>,sqrt(5)));

         2320     (1/2)
         ---- Pi 5     
          7            

Int(x^2*y^2,
    [ z = 4-sqrt(5-(x-2)^2-(y+3)^2) .. 4+sqrt(5-(x-2)^2-(y+3)^2),
      y = -3-sqrt(5-(x-2)^2) .. -3+sqrt(5-(x-2)^2),
      x = 2-sqrt(5) .. 2+sqrt(5) ]):

 simplify(value(%));

         2320     (1/2)
         ---- Pi 5     
          7
```